# Roots of unity (group theory)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation

Let $p$ be a prime and $T$ the set of ALL $n$-th roots of unity $\zeta_n \pmod p$: $T=[1, \zeta_n,  \zeta_n^2, \zeta_n^3...\zeta_n^{n-1}]$ ($n$ is odd). Find the smallest (non-empty) subset (in length) $S ⊂ T$ such that the sum of all elements in $S$ is $0\pmod p$. I suspect that the quickest way to accomplish this is the LLL Algorithm and hope that the coefficients of $\zeta_n^k$ are either $0$ or $1$ but I'm not sure.

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that anything as hifalutin as LLL could be the right way to go. But is $n$ supposed to be prime to $p$? And where are these roots of unity? Are you looking only within $\Bbb F_p=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$? Or are you starting with roots of unity as algebraic numbers, which you then want to look at in characteristic $p$ somehow?

Comment: The smallest subset such that the sum is $0$ is always $S=\varnothing$. If $q$ is the smallest prime dividing $n$, then the powers of $\zeta_n^{n/q}$ yield a set of size $q$. But to say more, it would help to clarify where these roots of unity are from.

Comment: @Lubin yes, working in $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$. With  $p=1\pmod n$, the elements in $S$ are the $n$-th roots of unity $\pmod p$. Then find a non-empty subset of $S$ whos sum is $0$.

Comment: Then have you looked at the case $n=9$, $p=37$? Or at the case $n=105$, $p=211$? Now that I understand your setup, the problem looks not at all deep to me.

Comment: @Lubin Yes, the solutions to those problems are well understood and easy to obtain. I am looking at where the cases are "hard" to solve: $p$ is exponential in $n$ ($n$ is somewhat small, and $p$ is relatively large): Examples include: $[n=105, p=26143331341]$, $[n=163,p=12623873548628794013]$, $[n=307,p=937341238029165472788205424455509587]$. Seem hard to solve, and no easy way of doing it.

Comment: I just realized: this is related to the centrifuge problem.

Comment: By *length* of $S$ do you mean just its cardinality, or the difference from the first included exponent to the last? Anyway, this is a bit like a modular knapsack problem, probably why you thought of LLL.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, I was directing this problem at the (minimal) cardinality of $S$, given the $p=1\pmod n$. The complexity of this problem is dependent on $p$. Thus, if $p$ is relatively small, this knapsack problem. Therefore, a good focus is on primes $p ≈ b^n$ where $b ≈ \sqrt 2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a contribution, but not an answer; let’s see whether I can explain why I think this is not a hard problem.

You have your number $n$ and a larger prime $p$, satisfying $n|(p-1)$. Let’s denote the field of integers modulo $p$ by $k$. We know that the set of nonzero elements, $k^\times$, is not only a group, but a cyclic group, and has a generator $g$, one of a (usually) large number of such. Now, if we call $(p-1)/n=d$, then $g^d$ generates a subgroup of order $(p-1)/d=n$, in other words, $g^d$ can be taken to be  your $\zeta_n$.

From here on, everything seems to take place in the subgroup $\langle g^d\rangle=T\subset k^\times$ of order $n$. In the same way as above, if $m|n$, then the $m$-th roots of $1$ in $k^\times$ form a (cyclic) subgroup of $T$ of order $m$, and if $\xi$ is a generator of this group, then $\{1,\xi,\cdots\xi^{m-1}\}$ form one of your sets $S$, since their sum is $(\xi^m-1)/(\xi-1)=0$. In particular, if $m$ is prime, you have a set of your type $S$ of cardinality $m$. I’d like to state with assurance that if you let $m$ be the smallest prime dividing $n$, then this set satisfies your minimality demand. But I’m unsure.

Certainly if $3$ is the smallest prime dividing $n$, then the group of cube roots of $1$ in $k$ is contained in $T$ and is minimal, since there is no $S$-set with only two elements, because $n$ is assumed even. So, of the two examples you offered in your comment, the first is easy: there’s an $S$ with $3$ elements, and no smaller nonempty such set. The second example catches me exactly where I’m on shakiest ground, since $307$ is prime. If my guess is correct, the only $S$-set here is $T$ itself.

**EDIT — Amendment**:

Your single example of elements of $\Bbb F_{53}$, $1+24+28\equiv0\pmod{53}$, where all three summands are $13$-th roots of unity, shows that I was certainly wrong in stating that this is not a hard problem. Further, I may have said it only in comments, but I was wrong to state that the containing field $\Bbb F_p$ was immaterial to the problem.

Perhaps I was looking through the wrong end of the telescope. If one looks even at the simplest case of your problem, to find three elements summing to zero in the (unique) subgroup of order $n$ in $\Bbb F_p^\times$ where necessarily $n|(p-1)$, then you can attack it in the following way, which makes my arguments seem particularly overoptimistic:

Once you normalize so that one of the elements of your triple is $1$, there’s a one-parameter family of triples adding to zero in $\Bbb F_p$, namely $\{1,a,-a-1\}$. There is absolutely no reason why all three couldn’t lie in some proper subgroup of $\Bbb F_p^\times$, even with your restriction that this subgroup should be of odd order.

Unfortunately, I have no idea and no tools in my kit that could help you with this problem.

Comment: Hmmm... the set $T$ itself is always a trivial solution. I was more curious of nontrivial solutions $S⫋T$. That is, $S$ is a subset not equal to $T$ but a solution to the original problem. I just go along with the fact that there are exactly $2^n$ proper subsets of $T$.

Comment: If $p<2^n$, then there should be at least one other subset $S$ (besides $T$) such that summing all the elements of $S$ is $0$. Therefore, we assume $p<2^n$ and one other non-trivial solution exists.

Comment: In my examples with $n=105,163,$ and $307$, $p<2^n$, so there are more solutions than just $T$. It could be a problem related to the subset sum problem in finite fields.

Comment: So sorry, of course I was being sloppy to say *anything* suggesting that the minimal set was unique. In the case $n=105$, for instance, the *size* of a minimal set will be $3$. I took as model the group of all cube roots of unity, call it $S_0$. Then if $\zeta$ is any $10-5$-th root of unity, any $\zeta S_0$ will also have three elements and have sum zero, so will satisfy your criteria.

Comment: (more:) There seems to be a Theorem that any subset of the $n$th roots of unity having sum zero must be built up from (multiplicative) translates of cyclic subgroups of order dividing $n$. So if $n$ is a prime (as are $163$ and $307$) then the *only* zero-sum subset is $T$ itself. I stress that all these things have no dependence whatever on $p$, save that $p-1$ must be a multiple of $n$.

Comment: Mersenne Primes $2^n-1$ seem to be a good example of this. For instance, $n=17$ and $p=2^13-1=8191$, $T=[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096]$ and the only subset $S$ of $T$ such that all elements in $S$ sum to $0$ $\pmod p$ is $T$ itself (good so far). Then I find if $p=53$ and  $T=[1, 10, 13, 15, 16, 24, 28, 36, 42, 44, 46, 47, 49]$. Then $S=[1, 24, 28]$ is a proper subset of $T$ (that is not $T$ itself) with sum $0 \pmod p$.

Comment: It's possible you referring to $0$ sums only excluding the $0 \pmod p$ part.

Comment: Hah! Most excellent example here, of $p=53$, the subgroup of all $13$-th roots of unity, with the subset $\{1,24,28\}$. This **destroys** my claim that the question is totally independent of the value of $p$.

Comment: Hmmm... there is a simple proof that if $p<2^{(n-1)/2}$, it is guaranteed to "destroy" your (previous) claim. There are obviously $2^n$ subsets of $T$, and when $p<2^{(n-1)/2}$, there are obviously two subsets $S$ and $S_2$ of length $(n-1)/2$ with congruent sums $\pmod p$ and the difference of these two sets produces one with sum $0 \pmod p$. Despite this, I still appreciate your effort on this problem.

Comment: I’ll think on this. Thanks for your patience!